# How to find intervals

Tags: javascript

[image]I will explain: it is necessary to make a step from the minimum number, ie from the minimum number in this case 11986913 + range in this case + 353584,3 and until we reach the maximum number , determined how many numbers are in the range, for example 11986913 + 353584,3 = 12 340 497.3 and determine how many numbers from this array are in this range

I made it to find min and max and range

```
let array = [
    11986913,
    12128796,
    12284564,
    12452765,
    12630047,
    12810118,
    12982023,
    13147666,
    13330769,
    13527845,
    13731794,
    13935560,
    14133509,
    14313965,
    14480596,
    14659880,
    14840502,
    15020573,
    15199720,
    15370419,
    15522756,
    ];
let max = getMaxValue(array);
let min = getMinValue(array);
 
function getMaxValue(array){
    var max = array[0]; 
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        if (max < array[i]) max = array[i]; 
    }
    console.log("Max number =", max);
}
 
function getMinValue(array){
    let min = array[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (min > array[i]) min = array[i];
    }
    console.log("Min number =", min);
}
 
k = 10
let stepLength = (15522756 - 11986913) / k;
console.log("Range = ", stepLength);
```

Comment: your functions `getMaxValue` and `getMinValue` don't return anything ... so `max` and `min` are undefined - but since you don't use them, that's not an issue I guess.

Comment: Now you've removed the for loop ... not sure what you even want - what is the expected result of the code

Comment: Yee, i know, its just error

Comment: can you provide the end solution/numbers that you expect us to help you out with ?

Comment: you code provides the following results in the console ... `Max number = 15522756
Min number = 11986913
Range =  353584.3` ... what else do you expect your code to do?

Comment: @vaira, Suppose there is an array of 10 numbers you need to find its minimum and maximum, then find the range (max - min) / 10.
And then from the minimum number (11986913) to go with this range until we reach the maximum number (15522756) and after each step you need to determine how many numbers are in this interval.

Comment: @Bravo, Suppose there is an array of 10 numbers you need to find its minimum and maximum, then find the range (max - min) / 10.
And then from the minimum number (11986913) to go with this range until we reach the maximum number (15522756) and after each step you need to determine how many numbers are in this interval.

Comment: why dont you just write what will be the final output of this code if written correctly, or do you not know the ouput?

Comment: but there isn't10 number  ... it's an array of 21 numbers in the question? why is 10 hard coded? why is maximum and minimum also hard coded for the stepLength? please add **to the question** expected result from your code - it'll explain much more than comments

Comment: @vaira
I can't show the end result, so I don't have it, I'm just telling the problem

Comment: how will you know if the solution is right? At the moment your question reads like *A train leaves Istanbul at 10 in the morning. It travels at 80km/h. What did the conductor have for breakfast? I don't know either, can you tell me*

Comment: We actually also dont know if you have written the question correctly, or if you have missed any other information.

Comment: even if we were to believe ur code totally wrong, are you sure the written part is exactly correct?

Comment: @Bravoб If I show a screen from the document, will it suit you?

Comment: @vaira, If I show a screen from the document, will it suit you?

Comment: Sure can give it a try

Comment: @vaira, I added the result

Comment: @vaira,
Oh sorry, I made a mistake there min 1 will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose there is an array of 10 numbers you need to find its minimum and maximum, then find the range (max - min) / 10. And then from the minimum number (11986913) to go with this range until we reach the maximum number (15522756) and after each step you need to determine how many numbers are in this interval.

This is what I came up with, I'm not exactely sure if I got your question correctly but I thought I'd give it a try.

```js
const array=[11986913,12128796,12284564,12452765,12630047,12810118,12982023,13147666,13330769,13527845,13731794,13935560,14133509,14313965,14480596,14659880,14840502,15020573,15199720,15370419,15522756];

const max = Math.max(...array); // get max
const min = Math.min(...array); // get min

const stepLength = ((max - min) / array.length) | 0; // calc step length
console.log("Range = ", stepLength);

for (let i = min; i < max; i += stepLength) { // loop over all seperate ranges
  const e = i + stepLength; // get end of range
  const numbers = array.filter(a => a >= i && a < e);
  console.log(`${numbers.length || "No"} numbers are in range [${i}, ${e}] >>`, numbers.join(', ')); // filter count of numbers that are between start and end range
}
```

Comment: Does it correctly count the number of numbers in the range?

Comment: I added a result that should be out

Comment: It is necessary to find how many numbers from the array are included in the given range

Comment: Exactely what this code does!

Comment: It does not correctly count the number of numbers included in the interval

Comment: It does, check the snippet out. Otherwise tell the correct output, you'd have expected.

Comment: Thanks it works. How else can you add to show all the numbers in the array and their number (for example, the number 11986913 - and its number, in this case 1)

Comment: Dont get your comment, `[11986913, 12155286]` includes two numbers (`11986913` and `12128796`)!

Comment: Here look we have us 21 number and it is necessary to deduce each number of an array and quantity of its repetitions in an array (that is there everywhere on 1 number) as numbers do not repeat

Comment: Thanks I decided this